# O365 Exchange search mailbox/es for email find read status?

Tags: c#, powershell, visual-studio-2012, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am trying to find out how to possibly search 1 or likely more, perhaps all o365 mailboxes for an email.  The search would be done using the subject and/or sender.

I then need to find out if the email was read and if possible the date/time it was read.

I have not worked with C#, only powershell, but I am willing to work to get it done, just can't find any examples as well as where to start. Do I need the EWS API V2.2, and then would it be Visual Studio, or can I do this another way that's easier?

Answer (score 1):

Is this you? :)
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/78c07af5-cbc6-4037-8ba8-2956e3ffba43/o365-ews-api-search-one-or-more-mailboxes-for-specific-email-check-if-read?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment

Same answer applies.

Comment: no, but that is what I am trying to do also and I will read the article. Thx